# Json Schema - Conditional Evaluation with RegEx

Tags: json, jsonschema

I've seen a couple of examples - most noticeably here - https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html - on the implementation of conditional schemas based on const or enum values of another field but am wondering if this is possible with a regular expression and not using another field to check against (i.e., what is the country and then apply the pattern on another field).

In my scenario, I want to validate if the postal code is formatted correctly for Canadian postal codes.  If it is great, if not, I then want to ensure that only the value "NA" is provided is allowed in this field.

```
  "if": {
    "properties": { "postalcode": { "pattern": "[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY][0-9][ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ] ?[0-9][ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][0-9])?" } }
  },
  "else": {
    "properties": { "postalcode": { "pattern": "NA" } }
  }
```

So once executed, unless I have a valid Canadian postal code or NA, everything else fails.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a conditional this time. `anyOf` will do the trick.

```
"properties": {
  "postalcode": {
    "type": "string",
    "anyOf":[
      { "pattern": "[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY][0-9][ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ] ?[0-9][ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][0-9])?" },
      { "const": "NA" }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I had not thought of this approach, thanks Jason.